# Remove server tag from http response header

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, http-headers, class-library

I am trying to remove server tag from http response headers in asp.net(C#)
With the help of stack overflow, I succeeded to create .dll file and added its reference in my project but still the server tag is visible in http headers. Below is the code for my .dll file.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
namespace ServerHeaders
{
public class CustomServerHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
    }
    public void Dispose() { }
    static void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // remove the "Server" Http Header
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");

    }
}
}
```

I have added reference to this file in web site and added required tag in web.config which is as below.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="CustomServerHeaderModule1" type="ServerHeaders.CustomServerHeaderModule" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings/>
    <client/>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Please guide me now what is still missing or is there any error?
I have fixed the error in `web.config`. Now it shows error in module at

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
```

The error is object reference is not set to an instance of the object. How to solve this error? I am running the project from local host(Using <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Web.dll` in the project?

Comment: @mellamokb..No. I have not added any reference. I just imported a namespace "System.web" Do I need to add the reference? if yes How?

Comment: @mellamokb. I have added reference. Now it ok. But how can I create a class library? Means how to run and create dll?

Comment: See if this [SF thread](http://serverfault.com/q/24885) helps...